# Traverse through a known structure in C

Tags: c, traversal

I am almost done with the rest of my assignment and now just need a print method to printout the structure that is obtained.

I want to know how to write a loop to traverse through a structure like this:

```
[""][ ][ ]-->  [""][ ][/]
     |              |              
   ["A"][/][/]     [""][ ][ ]-->  [""][ ][/]     
                        |              |                 
                      ["B"][/][/]    ["C"][/][/]
```

That is the structure for:

```
(a (b c))
```

OR

```
[""][ ][ ]-->  [""][ ][ ]--> [""][ ][/]
     |              |             |  
   ["A"][/][/]    ["B"][/][/]   ["C"][/][/]
```

This is for:

> (a b c)

Its code is:

```
struct conscell {
char symbol;
struct conscell *first;
struct conscell *rest;

};
```

So,the first space that you see is the symbol character, the next is a conscell pointer "first" and the last is a conscell pointer "rest".

Imagine, the structure is internally built (assignment done so far).

So now, after traversing through the structure, I should print out the appropriate list, with brackets.
For the above example, it would be

> (a (b c))

**I am done with the method: did a tree traversal with current nodes data(symbol), left node(first) and right node(rest). Just need to find where to put the brackets to get the correct output. 
Right now I get:**

> a b c

The print method:

```
// List is a pointer to struct conscell 
// myList will be the pointer referring to our first conscell structure  
void printList(List myList){
List current, pre;


if (myList == NULL)
    return;

current = myList;

while (current != NULL) {

    if (current->first == NULL) {
        printf("%c", current->symbol);
        current = current->rest;
    }
    else {
        /* Find the inorder predecessor of current */
        pre = current->first;
        while (pre->rest != NULL && pre->rest != current)
            pre = pre->rest;

        /* Make current as right child of its inorder predecessor */
        if (pre->rest == NULL) {
            pre->rest = current;
            current = current->first;
        }
            /* Revert the changes made in if part to restore the original 
              tree i.e., fix the right child of predecssor */
        else {
            pre->rest = NULL;
            printf("%c ", current->symbol);
            current = current->rest;
        } /* End of if condition pre->right == NULL */
    } /* End of if condition current->left == NULL*/

} /* End of while */
}
```

I'd be very grateful if someone can help me with this.

Comment: How do you describe `(a b c)` or `((a b) c)`?

Comment: ... and why shouldn't the description be `(a (b (c)))`?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I have added (a b c) and updated the question. I am able to traverse through it. Just need to know where to put the brackets to get the correct output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do it recursively.

Visit the first `concsell`, if `first != nullptr` visit the first element. Same thing for the `rest` member. And since all your elements have the same structure you are done.

You should only beware that if you have many elements your stack might overflow.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have updated the question. I used tree traversal method to go through the entire structure, however, I am not able to figure out where I should put the brackets '(' and ')' to get the correct output.

Comment: Just close the brackets after you are done with every `concsell` object, that is, after you visited the `rest` member. That should do it for your examples.